# Best practice when passing Redux state into components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working on a React + Redux project with a couple of other developers and we can't agree on what the best practice is regarding where to pass in the state and the actions.

My approach is to have a 'container' or 'provider' component, which is the parent component, all required states and actions are mapped to state and passed down into child components, creating a single source of truth. However the down side to that is, you have to remember to pass actions and values down through each child component, which can be tricky to follow.

Another developers approach is to use the `mapStateToProps` on each component where it is needed, at any point in the stack. So if a child component three or four levels down requires a certain state, he would use mapStateToProps on that component. He would also import action creators directly using the `import` keyword, instead of calling them as props. I don't like this approach because you're potentially injecting states multiple times and you can't switch out your state or actions quickly in one place.

I can see both approaches have their merits and fallbacks, so I just wondered if there was a definite best practice as to where and when to inject state/actions into a stack of React components.

Comment: I tend towards Jeremy's answer, but there's no hard and fast "rule" regarding this, it's more about opinion and how you want to structure things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I worked on a relatively large Redux codebase and the approach we chose and which I like was your second approach using `mapStateToProps` on **containers** component which dispatch actions and delegate rendering to dumb **components**.

You want to be able to reuse them in many places without having to pass down a state. Your top redux state is still the source of truth but `mapStateToProps` will allow you to access only the part of the state which you need within this container.

Redux documentation is amazingly well done, check it out, it recommends container components implementing `mapStateToProps` http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

Comment: I completely agree on mapStateToProps on containers component which dispatch actions and delegate rendering to dumb components +1.

Comment: So would it be legitimate to use container components say... half way down the stack? So a container component, which calls a dumb component, which say... calls another container component?

Comment: Yes ! Half way down or all the way down even. The idea is that then you can use your container component anywhere and it should be agnostic of its environment, that is the beauty of Redux.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you how many components you connect to Redux, but generally speaking having more connected components is better for performance.  For more information, see the [Redux FAQ on connecting multiple components](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components), as well as my blog post [Practical Redux, Part 6: Connected Lists, Forms, and Performance](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-6-connected-lists-forms-and-performance/).